# Bash not executing from command line

Tags: windows, bash, cmd.exe, system32

**Description:**

I am not able to execute `bash` from my command line opened from desktop. I have to `cd` to `system32` to run it.

**Error message:**

> 'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

**Expected results:**

After I enter `bash` in the `cmd`, the Windows Subsystem for Linux opens in the current directory.

**Extra:**

I have enabled Windows Subsystem for Linux, and `bash` works fine on the Ubuntu app. I think there is a `PATH` issue, but not sure how to fix it.

*Windows Developer Mode* is enabled. *Legacy Console* is unchecked.

**System environment variables with their values:**

```
ComSpec                  C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
DriverData               C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
NUMBER OF_PROCESSORS     8
OS                       Windows_NT
Path                     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin;C:\Pr...
PATHEXT                  .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE   AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER     Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 12, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL          6
PROCESSOR_REVISION       8e0c
PSModulePath             %ProgramFiles%\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\s...
TEMP                     C:\Windows\TEMP
TMP                      C:\Windows\TEMP
USERNAME                 SYSTEM
windir                   C:\Windows
```

**Search results in System32**

```
bash.exe.mui                                    Date modified: 2020-07-03 7:33 PM
C:\Windows\System32\en-US   Type: MUI File      Size: 4.50 KB

bash.exe                                        Date modified: 2020-01-01 10:10 PM
C:\Windows\System32         Type: Application   Size: 118 KB
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Cause of error**

There is a bug with windows thinking legacy console is activated when it is actually unchecked.

**Solution**

Steps:

1. Open Command Prompt
2. Right Click the top bar, and press *Properties*
3. Go to options tab, and check Legacy console
4. Relaunch command Prompt
5. Go back to the options tab, and uncheck the Legacy console
6. Relaunch
7. Windows BUG: The command prompt is most likely a black box with no text
8. Go to Properties, and then the Terminal tab
9. Uncheck `Use separate foreground` and 'Use separate backround'
10. Now type `bash` in cmd and it should work flawlessly.

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

### Windows Subsystem for Linux

There is used currently **Windows 10 1903** according to Windows update history records. My first recommendation is to upgrade to currently latest Windows 10 which is **Windows 10 2004** using the Microsoft page [Download Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10) if that is possible. There have been lots of improvements on *Windows Subsystem for Linux* (WSL) like introducing [Windows Subsystem for Linux **2**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-index) as it can be read for example on Wikipedia page [Windows 10 version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history) for *Version 2004 (May 2020 Update)*. The *Windows Developer Mode* should be disabled before starting the Windows 10 upgrade.

---

### Cause of the error

The error is caused by starting 32-bit Windows command processor in `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` instead of 64-bit version in `%SystemRoot%\System\cmd.exe`. For that reason the Windows [File System Redirector](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) is active when 32-bit Windows command processor takes `C:\Windows\System32` from **local** environment variable `PATH` to search for a file with name `bash` with a file extension as defined in **local** environment variable `PATEXT` resulting in searching in directory `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` for `bash`. But there is no `bash.exe` in Windows system directory for 32-bit applications. Therefore no `bash.exe` is found by 32-bit `cmd.exe`.

Please read on Stack Overflow [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) for more details about how `cmd.exe` uses `PATH` and `PATHEXT` and how these two very important environment variables can be configured by a user.

---

### Solution 1: Using 64-bit Windows command processor

The first solution is opening a 64-bit [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) by starting `%SystemRoot%\System\cmd.exe` instead of `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` on 64-bit Windows.

This is definitely the best and easiest to achieve solution.

---

### Solution 2: Run BASH with full qualified file name

The second solution is running `bash` from within 32-bit command prompt window with full qualified file name using the special alias `Sysnative` which means typing `C:\Windows\Sysnative\bash.exe` instead of just `bash`.

See also the Microsoft documentation [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).

This is definitely the best solution on using already the 32-bit Windows environment.

---

### Solution 3: Hard link to bash.exe

**Attention:** This solution is not recommended for long time usage!

The third solution is starting `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` as administrator with clicking with secondary (right) mouse button on this file in Windows File Explorer and clicking on context menu item **Run as administrator** to explicitly start 32-bit Windows command processor with elevated privileges of local administrator.

Next enter following command line:

```
mklink /H %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\bash.exe %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\bash.exe
```

That creates a hard link with name `bash.exe` in directory `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` to file `bash.exe` in `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative`. Then 32-bit `cmd.exe` can find a file `bash.exe` in `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` which results in execution of `%SystemRoot%\System32\bash.exe` in Windows system directory for 64-bit applications.

Run in command prompt window `mklink /?` for help on this command or read even better SS64 documentation of [MKLINK](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html).

**Note:** It is advisable to delete that hard link with `del %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\bash.exe` executed in a command prompt window opened with **Run as administrator** before doing a Windows update or Windows upgrade which updates `%SystemRoot%\System32\bash.exe` and recreate the hard link after newer `bash.exe` is installed by the Windows update/upgrade.

I don't recommend using this solution as it could cause easily troubles in future.

---

### Solution 4: Creation of bash.cmd

**Attention:** This solution is not recommended for compatibility with batch files containing `bash`!

The fourth solution is starting `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` as administrator with clicking with secondary (right) mouse button on this file in Windows File Explorer and clicking on context menu item **Run as administrator** to explicitly start 32-bit Windows command processor with elevated privileges of local administrator.

Next enter following command line:

```
echo @%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\bash.exe %*>%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\bash.cmd
```

That command line creates with Windows installed into `C:\Windows` the batch file `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bash.cmd` with the single command line:

```
@C:\Windows\Sysnative\bash.exe %*
```

So 32-bit `cmd.exe` finds now on entering just `bash` in a 32-bit Windows command prompt window the file `bash.cmd` in `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` on using directory path `C:\Windows\System32` in **local** environment variable `PATH` redirected by file system redirector to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`. The batch file runs `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe` with all parameters specified on starting `bash.cmd` passed to `bash.exe`.

**Note:** A Windows batch file containing just `bash` executed by 32-bit Windows command processor results in starting `bash.exe` via `bash.cmd`, but then no more command lines in batch file are executed by `cmd.exe` because of Windows command processor ends batch file execution on finishing execution of `bash.cmd` executed without usage of command **CALL** from initially executed batch file. So this solution is not safe to use for batch files containing just the file name `bash` executed by 32-bit `cmd.exe`.

I don't recommend using this solution as it could cause troubles with batch files.

---

### Conclusion

There are definitely even more solutions, but best is running 64-bit Windows command processor on 64-bit Windows to have unrestricted access to all executables ported from Linux and installed by default with Windows 10 like `bash.exe` or the executables in directory `%SystemRoot%\System32\OpenSSH` which exist also only as 64-bit executables.